# Converting json to pandas dataframe with weather datasets

Tags: python, json, pandas

How can we convert this to dataframes? I have tried multiple ways on how it can be achived, i have tried with json file on w3school but it is working correctly, i am new with python, any recommendations on this?
Json format is

```
[
  {
    "id": 14256,
    "city": {
      "id": {
        "$numberLong": "14256"
      },
      "name": "Azadshahr",
      "findname": "AZADSHAHR",
      "country": "IR",
      "coord": {
        "lon": 48.570728,
        "lat": 34.790878
      },
      "zoom": {
        "$numberLong": "10"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": {
      "$numberLong": "465726"
    },
    "city": {
      "id": {
        "$numberLong": "465726"
      },
      "name": "Zadonsk",
      "findname": "ZADONSK",
      "country": "RU",
      "coord": {
        "lon": 38.926102,
        "lat": 52.3904
      },
      "zoom": {
        "$numberLong": "16"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The expected output is :

[image]

it tried to do a conversion but i am receiving error and it is not the whole data

```
with open('data/history.city.list.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

but not able to load as data, This is what i have tried but i feel

```
_id = []
country = []
coord_lat = []
coord_lon = []

counter = 0
for i in data:
    _id.append(data[counter]['id'])
    country.append(data[counter]['city']['country'])
    coord_lat.append(data[counter]['city']['coord']['lon'])
    coord_lat.append(data[counter]['city']['coord']['lat'])
    counter += 1
```

When i have tried to print it as a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Longtitude' : coord_lat , 'Latitude' : coord_lat})    
df.head(10)
```

This was able to set it to dataframe, but as soon as i add 'Country' to pd.dataframe() , it will return as ValueError: arrays must all be same length.

i understand that country column does not match the other columns but can we achieve this and is there a simpler way to do it ?

Comment: For now and always, when "having an error", "program does not do what i expect", please detail this, give the error, give the current output and the expected one (if they exist) this is more info to help you, Also you should show real effort to solve your problem, not just read the file ;)

Comment: @azro , i have already updated my question and tried ways on how it can be converted to dataframe. only thing is , i dont really understand how can we split it on json to pandas dataframe

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. This really helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_normalize() as described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
import pandas as pd

d = [
  {
    "id": 14256,
    "city": {
      "id": {
        "$numberLong": "14256"
      },
      "name": "Azadshahr",
      "findname": "AZADSHAHR",
      "country": "IR",
      "coord": {
        "lon": 48.570728,
        "lat": 34.790878
      },
      "zoom": {
        "$numberLong": "10"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": {
      "$numberLong": "465726"
    },
    "city": {
      "id": {
        "$numberLong": "465726"
      },
      "name": "Zadonsk",
      "findname": "ZADONSK",
      "country": "RU",
      "coord": {
        "lon": 38.926102,
        "lat": 52.3904
      },
      "zoom": {
        "$numberLong": "16"
      }
    }
  }
]

pd.io.json.json_normalize(d)
```

Output:

```
    id          city.id.$numberLong     city.name   city.findname   city.country    city.coord.lon  city.coord.lat  city.zoom.$numberLong   id.$numberLong
0   14256.0     14256                  Azadshahr    AZADSHAHR      IR               48.570728      34.790878       10   NaN
1   NaN         465726                 Zadonsk      ZADONSK        RU               38.926102      52.390400        16  465726
```

The column names do not match your expected output, but you can change that easily with df.columns = ['Id', 'city', ... 'Zoom']